# PactNet - HttpPost Test Fails with 500 internal server error

Tags: .net-core, pact, pact-net

I am trying to send an HTTP Post request from my test method to my Pactnet mock service. The following is the log generated -

**[INFO][pact_mock_server::hyper_server] Received request HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /api/v1/post-txn, query: None, headers: Some({"host": ["127.0.0.1:62047"], "content-length": ["160"], "content-type": ["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}), body: Present(160 bytes, application/json;charset=utf-8) ) 


[INFO][pact_matching] comparing to expected HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /api/v1/post-txn, query: None, headers: Some({"Content-Type": ["application/json; charset=utf-8"]}), body: Present(114 bytes, application/json) )**

For me, it looks like the received request and the expected request look the same from the log information. However, the test is unsuccessful with the below exception message -

**{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-pact: Request-Mismatch
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2022 05:16:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 648
}}**

Could someone help me what is wrong with my received request and expected request, and where there is a mismatch as mentioned in the exception details? I have spent a lot of time debugging, yet I am unable to find what exactly the issue is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Internal Server Error would tend to mean something is wrong with the code.

Comment: If I remove the below line from my PactBuilder properties then it is returning success -                                           
 .WithJsonBody(new { TransactionId = "test_txn_Id", JsonPayload = "Json Payload", DateTimeCreated = "test" })                                                                                                         Does it mean there is an issue with the way am setting up the Body?

Comment: I've no idea.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to the DateTime format?

Comment: Have you faced a similar issue Eduardo? and did you find a fix?

Answer (score -2):

If you increase the log level to debug you should be able to compare the JSON body in the request to what's expected. The body looks to be different as I dictated by the number of bytes expected vs actual.

Additionally, there should be an error message to indicate why it failed. If not that could be a bug.

The header content type also looks different on close inspection

Comment: Even with log level set to debug the problem is not clear in my case